# Ionic app fails to run with error options must be an object

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have an Ionic app that fails with the following error. Any idea how to resolve or tips how to debug? (Cordova 5.1.1 + Ionic 1.4.3)

```
I/chromium(13497): [INFO:CONSOLE(20434)] "Error: "options" must be an object!
I/chromium(13497): at Object.N._ (file:///android_asset/www/lib/js-data.min.js:11:26882)
I/chromium(13497): at file:///android_asset/www/lib/js-data.min.js:10:23334
I/chromium(13497): at new a (file:///android_asset/www/lib/js-data-angular.min.js:10:1479)
I/chromium(13497): at g.d [as findAll] (file:///android_asset/www/lib/js-data.min.js:10:23262)
I/chromium(13497): at function._this.(anonymous function).defineResource.def.(anonymous function) (file:///android_asset/www/lib/js-data.min.js:11:6366)
I/chromium(13497): at f.service.findAll (file:///android_asset/www/js/application.js:4795:24)
I/chromium(13497): at loadTasks (file:///android_asset/www/js/application.js:2314:19)
I/chromium(13497): at file:///android_asset/www/js/application.js:2375:18
I/chromium(13497): at processQueue (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22016:27)
I/chromium(13497): at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22032:27", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js (20434)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually a problem with the cordova-android versioning. Since cordova 5.1.1 the default cordova-android is 4.0.2, which defaults to android-22. you probably need a previous version.

try this:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@3.7.2
```

Comment: awesome! you saved the day